# What is the best solution to transmit data by the ionosphere over at least 7500 km?

Tags: ionosphere

I know that some amateur radio are using some frequencies that are reflecting on the ionosphere to transmit data over super long distances. I am wondering if it is possible, without an insane lot of power and with relatively portable antenna (on a reduced model of boat that would be about 2*3 meters) to transmit data in this way over at least 7500 kilometers ?

EDIT : Finally, the boat might be smaller : 1.6 meters on 0.6 meters. This boat might have an AI so I think that it wouldn't be that problematic if the connection was lost at some moments. The minimum of data to transmit is instructions for the boat to tell it where to go, but it would be great to transmit photos and videos. I am not a licensed amateur radio operator.

Comment: Is your boat communicating with a station back on land? Is that station in a fixed position? Is that station in a location where it could be possible to install a radio antenna tower?

Comment: Comments must be at least 15 characters but the answer isn't: "no."

Comment: @BenSwayne I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

With your project, is it necessary to always have the ability to communicate? Or can you batch up your data and wait for the conditions to be suitable and transmit back a batch of data? A little more information about your project and the type of data you wish to transmit may be helpful in answering this question (or even determining if amateur radio is suitable at all). Consider [editing your question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/1725/edit) to include more detail.

HF propagation varies dramatically from non-functional to miraculous depending on all sorts of conditions: time of day, solar activity, weather, etc. You can compensate for less than perfect conditions with more power, better antenna, more directional antennas, antenna elevation, etc. But its hard to make any recommendation without knowing more about your project.

Are you already a licensed amateur radio operator? If not, I'd highly suggest you begin the process! You will start learning about radio functionality including propagation and can start experimenting with various radios and antennas.

Comment: While we appreciate your enthusiasm, Ben, this answer runs the risk of becoming completely obsolete if/when the OP updates the question with more detail. The request for more details (which frankly most of this answer is all about) is what comments on the question, not *answers*, are meant for.

Comment: I edited my post !